# Using service from injected module - NestJS

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

I'm trying to use a service from a services module in the main scaffolded app controller in NestJS.

This is working - helloWorldsService.message displays the expected greeting in the @Get method - but the imports of HelloWorldsService in app.module and app.controller seem redundant, and seems to violate encapsulation of the services by the services module.

Do I have this right, is this how you consume a discreet service from a different module, or am I missing something?  The reason I ask is: if this is correct, and you have to directly reference the other classes (e.g. reference HelloWorldService directly in the controller), then I have trouble seeing why one bothers with the providers/imports properties of the @Module declaration.

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { RouterModule } from './router/router.module';
import { ServicesModule } from './services/services.module'; //<-- import service MODULE
import { EventsModule } from './events/events.module';
import { HelloWorldsService } from './services/hello-worlds/hello-worlds.service'; //<-- import service module SERVICE


@Module({
  imports: [RouterModule, ServicesModule, EventsModule],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService, HelloWorldsService],
})
export class AppModule {}


//Controller code:
import { Controller, Get } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { HelloWorldsService } from './services/hello-worlds/hello-worlds.service'; //<-- importing service again in consuming controller

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService, private readonly helloWorldsService: HelloWorldsService ) {}

    @Get()
    getHello(): string {
        return this.helloWorldsService.Message();
    }
}


//services.module
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { WagerAccountService } from './wager-account/wager-account.service';
import { WagerAccountHttpService } from './wager-account.http/wager-account.http.service';
import { CustomerIdentityHttpService } from './customer-identity.http/customer-identity.http.service';
import { HelloWorldsService } from './hello-worlds/hello-worlds.service';

@Module({
    exports:[HelloWorldsService],
  providers: [CustomerIdentityHttpService, WagerAccountService, WagerAccountHttpService, CustomerIdentityHttpService, HelloWorldsService]
})
export class ServicesModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use some services in another service, there are different ways, depends on what's your goal. For example: You have `App1Service` and `App1Module`, `App2Service` and `App2Module` and want to use `App2Service` in `App1Service`

1. You can use `providers`

```
// App1Module.ts
@Module({
 imports: [],
 controllers: [App1Controller],
 providers: [App1Service, App2Service], // only service is imported here
})
export class App1Module {}
```

2. Import full `Module` but don't forget to `export` the service

```
// App1Module.ts
@Module({
 imports: [App2Module], // Full Module is imported here
 controllers: [App1Controller],
 providers: [App1Service], // No need to use service import here but need to export App2Module services
})
export class App1Module {}
```

`App2Service` MUST be exported in `App2Module`

```
// App2Module.ts
@Module({
  imports: [],
  controllers: [App2Controller],
  providers: [App2Service],
  exports: [App2Service] // this service is exported and available in other services
})
export class App2Module {}
```

If you have some dependency in `App2Module` to other Modules, e.g `App3Module` and want to use `App3Service` in `App1Service` you should use Option 2. Export `App3Service` in `App3Module` and it will be automatically available for `App1Service`. That's how it works:

1. You export `App3Service` in `App3Module`
2. You import `App3Module` in `App2Module`
3. You import `App2Module` in `App1Module`

Comment: thank you @BidzinaAivazashvili.  I do export the service in service.module, and I import the module in the AppModule class. So, it's working... it just throws me that I have import statements in my AppModule class for the imported modules and services, and import statements in my consuming controller as well.  You are saying this is fine?

Comment: @monkeydeus When you say "import statements in my consuming controller" do you mean dependency injection in your controller constructor?